# My Insert queries is blocking my select queries. CPU usage of server goes upto 100% for postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am using select and insert queries on a table. but CPU usage goes upto 100% for postgres. How can I optimize it

Table structure and queries are as follow

```
CREATE TABLE ad_request
(
    request_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    client_id integer DEFAULT 0,
    ad_type integer DEFAULT 0,
    ad_unit integer DEFAULT 0,
    host_url character varying(150) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    ip_address character varying(20) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    referer character varying(350) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    platform character varying(20) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    browser character varying(20) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    served_campaign_id bigint DEFAULT 0,
    status character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
    created_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT ad_request_pkey PRIMARY KEY (request_id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE ad_request
    OWNER TO postgres;


SELECT served_campaign_id
FROM ad_request
WHERE client_id=1 AND ad_type=1 AND ad_unit=1 AND ip_address='192.168.1.1' AND created_time > current_timestamp - interval '24 HOUR';

INSERT INTO
ad_request(client_id,ad_type,ad_unit,host_url,ip_address,referer,platform,browser,served_campaign_id)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE for seelct query is

```
 Seq Scan on ad_request  (cost=0.00..52629.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=245.512..245.512 rows=0 loops=1)
 Filter: ((client_id = 1) AND (ad_type = 1) AND (ad_unit = 1) AND     ((ip_address)::text = '192.168.1.1'::text) AND (created_time > (now() -   '24:00:00'::interval)))
 Total runtime: 245.544 ms
 (3 rows)
```

and output of Insert Query is

```
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.092..0.094 rows=1 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.198 ms
 (2 rows)
```

and ouput of  SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid; is

```
datid | datname | procpid | usesysid | usename  |                                     current_query                                   | waiting |          xact_start
   |          query_start          |         backend_start         |   client_addr | client_port |  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple |   virtualxid | tran
  sactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |       mode       | granted
   -------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------  ---------------
   -------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+-----
  ----------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+-----------------+---------
   20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM  pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |  2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
    012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |             |          -1 | relation   |    20916 |    10969 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 | AccessShareLock | t
    20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |   2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
   012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |             |          -1 | relation   |        0 |     1262 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 |   AccessShareLock | t
    20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM  pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |    2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
   012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |             |          -1 | relation   |        0 |     1260 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 | AccessShareLock | t
   20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |    2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
   012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |             |          -1 | relation   |        0 |     2671 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 | AccessShareLock | t
    20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |  2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
    012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |             |          -1 | relation   |        0 |     2676 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 | AccessShareLock | t
  20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |  2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
  012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |             |          -1 | virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 1/1272802  |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 |  ExclusiveLock   | t
   20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM  pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |    2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
  012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |              |          -1 | relation   |    20916 |    11042 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 |  AccessShareLock | t
   20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM  pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |  2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
 012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |              |          -1 | relation   |        0 |     2672 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 |  AccessShareLock | t
   20916 | adtag   |    1307 |       10 | postgres | SELECT * FROM  pg_stat_activity pga inner join pg_locks pl on pga.procpid=pl.pid ; | f       |  2015-04-01 06:00:27.700
   012+00 | 2015-04-01 06:00:27.700012+00 | 2015-04-01 04:04:49.810039+00 |              |          -1 | relation   |        0 |     2677 |      |       |            |
      |         |       |          | 1/1272802          | 1307 |  AccessShareLock | t
  (9 rows)
```

Comment: When the documentation says that "insert doesn't block select", it means that select doesn't require any locks that insert takes, so inserts can happen while selects are happening at the same time. It's still possible for lots of inserts to slow SELECTs down because of the system load created, to the point where they seem to not be running.

Comment: In this case some more detail is required. Describe the behaviour you see. Show the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT ...` for your queries. If they never finish, use plain `EXPLAIN` instead of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Paste the results here. Also paste the output of `\copy (SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity inner join pg_locks using (pid)) to stdout with (format csv, header on)` run in `psql` *while the queries are "blocked"* please. **Comment here when you've edited your question to add this info** and remember to use the `{}` button to code-indent it!

Comment: I have added the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT and EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT

Comment: Well, how is it "blocking" then? Both queries seemed to complete normally and there's nothing in pg_stat_activity to suggest otherwise.

Comment: The SELECT has to use a sequential scan because you don't have any indexes at all. Your query could at least use an index on client_id, but other columns (or combinations of columns) might be useful as well. But it all depends on your data, you have to test this yourself.